# NSG and routing details to connect a Microsoft Flow with Azure SQL database in a VNET

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, power-automate, azure-sql-server, azure-nsg

I have a SQL Server DB in  a VM in a VNET in an Azure Subscription . Currently it does not have any connection open to the Internet .

My application team has designed a Microsoft Flow application that will read some emails , parse them in some way and push those files into the sql server database (local storage).

I cannot open my VM NSG to the entire internet. What NSG Rules do I need to implement?

Comment: Do you use an Azure SQL database(Paas) or just a database hosted in Azure VM?

Comment: @NancyXiong I use a database that is hosted in an axure vm as of now .

Comment: Microsoft Flow application is located on a local computer or on Azure?

Comment: @NancyXiong Microsoft flow is Microsoft's workflow as a service tool. I assume it is hosted  by Microsoft in their own data centers

Answer (score 0):

The IP address from which Microsoft Flow requests are sent depends on [the region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/regions-overview) where the [environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/environments-overview-admin) that contains the flow is located. If you want to access SQL Database hosted on Azure VM from your Microsoft Flow application, you may whitelist [these IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/limits-and-config#ip-address-configuration).

Then you could follow these steps in  [how to open ports to a virtual machine with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) to open port 1433 and protocol. You have configured the outbound IP addresses above in the **source IP addresses**  and **dest port range** 1433 in the inbound rule of NSG. Also, you need to ensure the same inbound traffic flow in VM itself firewall.

Comment: This does not help me . I am aware of this . This is extremely basic azure networking concept .I need specific answers like what cidr to whitelist and so on.

Comment: @TurjaChaudhuri re-edit my reply. May I know if there is any update or process on your side?